# How to pass a OAuth2 authentication token from MVC5 wepapplication to a WebAPI2 application

Tags: .net, oauth-2.0, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2, cross-domain

I am having some troubles setting up a project with OAuth2, WebAPI2 and a interface.

**The scenario:**

I am setting up a project which is basically a WebApi2. This WebApi provides de business logic and the data for my interfaces.

For now the interface is a MVC5 webapplication, but in the future I want to be able to hook up some other 'Apps' to it. This is where the CORS come in: the interface and WebAPI can be at different servers.

I would like to use OAuth2, so users can register thru Google and other providers.

**The question:**

It concerns the signup part:

At first I tried to sign-up to the interface MVC application and try to pass the authentication token to the WebAPI. This didn't seem to be the correct way to implement this.

Now I am thinking to expose a signup interface in the WebApi project, so users will be redirected to the Api if they signup at the MVC webapplication. But this will give worries, because for every action on the MVC webapplication, a "is this user authenticated" call is required.

Does anybody know which of the two options (or maybe a third) is preferable?

I know this is quite broad, but please be gentle ;-)

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services on how to implement external authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite a bit question on architectural Part.

To be  gentle.Second approach seems complicated in that you have two UI Interface considering over all application for (MVC5 Application and now WebAPI for Signup)

thus by doing you will make your Interface more dependant on API Project making it tightly coupled.

In the first approach ,If only security is the impediment for you then you can encrypt/decrypt token before and after service call to your web API project.

and with the first approach you can Persist the Authentication of User on ur Interface/Presentation Layer in local storage or session

WebApi itself is meant for Distributed Communication between the Application and other components of system such as Business Layer.

but you already has Interface Layer so i think there is no need of making WebApi heavy with User Interface.

First Approach would be good.

Answer (score 1):

Our project has the same architecture.

MVC Site -> Web API(business) -> Web API(data)

Business API will be opened to third party developers, so we need an OAuth2 authentication.

Web API can only open some functions, not all, maybe you would use the "Scope", but for us, there are only two kinds of API, API for third party and API for our site.

So we did something in authenticate handler, there is a "Bearer" scheme for authorization header, why not a new one for our site?

Then it works. Just define a new scheme for MVC site, eg. "ASPX", and store the forms cookie from site, resolve it.

We can also know where the request from since the header scheme is different.

BTW, you should take care the name of scheme.

Comment: Make sure the API server & MVC site server have the same machinekey setting before decrypting cookie